# Declare functions in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a complex function with pgfplots using `declare function`. As it does not compile, I have tried to nail down the issue. It seems that, when I define a function from another function, it creates a problem. Here is the minimum example that illustrates the problem. Can somebody help me?

The following code compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function = {
      U1(\x,\b) = \b * \x - 0.5 ;
      P(\x, \b) = U1(\x, \b) ;
    }
  ]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot {U1(x,2)} ;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the following code does not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function = {
      U1(\x,\b) = \b * \x - 0.5 ;
      P(\x, \b) = U1(\x, \b) ;
    }
  ]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot {P(x,2)} ;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmathfloat@expression.
<to be read again>
                   \crcr
l.12     \addplot {P(x,2)} ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove the space in `P(\x, \b) = ...`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function = {
      U1(\x,\b) = \b * \x - 0.5 ;
      P(\x,\b) = U1(\x, \b) ; % <------ space removed
    }
  ]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot {P(x,2)} ;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed. It works now. Interesting. Thanks a lot.